# VueJS: Displaying form input in list and modal

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to:

1. display form input (name, position, company) as an unordered list (v-for) which lists just the name inputted and a button for each person
2. if click button, a modal appears which displays all the data inputted for that person (name, company, position) (**array of objects?)

Code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/testing-2s8xvi?file=/src/components/EmployeeTable.vue

What logic looks like in vanilla JS (accessing data as array of objects, note use of .myParam to retrieve the object in array for a specific person): `enter code here`https://codepen.io/walrus2/pen/wvmoQOP

Would appreciate your help and suggestions, thank you in advance

Comment: So you want to migrate this vanilla JS code into Vue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, You want to migrate that vanilla JS code into a Vue code. If Yes, Here you go **:**

Note : I did not add any validations in below demo, Please add as per your requirement.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    formObj: {
        name: null,
      position: null,
      company: null
    },
    usersList: [],
    isShowDetails: false,
    modalContent: null
  },
  methods: {
    createList() {
      const obj = structuredClone(this.formObj);
        this.usersList.push(obj);
    },
    showDetails(id) {
        this.isShowDetails = true;
      this.modalContent = this.usersList.find((obj, index) => index === id);
    },
    closeModal() {
        this.isShowDetails = false;
    }
  }
})
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: block; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <label>name:</label><br/>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" v-model="formObj.name"/><br/><br/>

  <label>position:</label><br/>
  <input type="text" id="position" name="position" v-model="formObj.position"/><br/><br/>

  <label>company:</label><br />
  <input type="text" id="company" name="company" v-model="formObj.company"/><br/><br/>

  <button @click="createList()">Submit</button>

  <ul>
    <li v-for="(user, index) in usersList" :key="index">
      {{ user.name }}
      <button @click="showDetails(index)">Show Details</button>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div id="myModal" class="modal" v-if="isShowDetails">

    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <span class="close" @click="closeModal">&times;</span>
      <p>name: <span id="modalText1">{{ modalContent.name }}</span></p>
      <p>position: <span id="modalText2">{{ modalContent.position }}</span></p>
      <p>company: <span id="modalText3">{{ modalContent.company }}</span></p>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. I used export default instead of new vue syntax, but get a "Strutured clone is not defined" error - is there a way to achieve same result without structuredclone? https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-goldstine-fgtwmy?file=/src/App.vue Also, may I know more about your thought process, any tips for how to convert sth from vanilla JS to vue?

Comment: @shatterstar You can achieve the same result by `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.formObj))` but `structuredClone` should work as it supports in all the browsers.

Comment: @shatterstar Here is the updated codesandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-bardeen-tzq33t

Comment: Thank you so much. Sorry one more question: do you have any suggestions for a beginner on how to change vanilla JS code to vue, are there any things you think about first? For example, with this I would have thought to use components but wasn't sure how to pass things around.

Comment: @shatterstar It's totally based on the requirement. You can read about how components has been created, how data binding works, life cycle hooks. Also, Kindly do accept and upvote this answer if it helps you so that it will be helpful for others as well.

Comment: apparently there is min requirement for reputation to upvote answer, I tried but didnt work. Appreciate ur help!

Comment: @shatterstar It should not be the case. As you are a post owner, you have the privilege to accept the answer and upvote.

Comment: Thks, I managed to accept the answer. However, as mentioned when I try to upvote, there is a popup that says I don't meet the requirement to do so. Sorry! When I hit that reputation mark I'll upvote.